# No Connection in SessionDescription

Tags: sip, sdp

I'm using the Sdp class from the Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling namespace.

Now I want to parse the following Sdp-Text:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.253.202
s=session
c=IN IP4 239.168.253.202
t=0 0
m=message 5060 sip null
a=accept-types:text/plain
```

using the following code:

```
var text = @"v=0
             o=- 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.253.202
             s=session
             c=IN IP4 239.168.253.202
             t=0 0
             m=message 5060 sip null
             a=accept-types:text/plain
             ";

Sdp<SdpGlobalDescription, SdpMediaDescription> sessionDescription2 = new Sdp<SdpGlobalDescription, SdpMediaDescription>();

var encodedText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
if (sessionDescription2.TryParse(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length, false))
{
    sessionDescription2.Dump();
    IList<SdpMediaDescription> activeMediaTypes = sessionDescription2.MediaDescriptions;
    foreach (var sdpMediaDescription in activeMediaTypes)
    {
        sdpMediaDescription.Dump();
        foreach (var sdpBandwidth in sdpMediaDescription.Bandwidths)
        {
            sdpBandwidth.Dump();
        }
        foreach (var sdpAttribute in sdpMediaDescription.Attributes)
        {
            sdpAttribute.Dump();
        }
    }
}
else
{
    sessionDescription2.LastParseErrorMessage.Dump();
    sessionDescription2.LastParseErrorLineNumber.Dump();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

.Dump() is from nuget ConsoleDump Package.

All information is parsed but the 'c' connection is set to null.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

That was easy.

I must look in sessionDescription2.GlobalDescription - there it is!